# temporary field for recovery password

Tags: java, spring, date

when I restore a password, a password is generated in my project, with which you can log in to your account and change the password, I can’t understand how to limit the temporary password field by time? let's say that the user can log in using this password for an hour, I have a date field for the password, but I don't know what to compare it with

```
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails {

    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date lastPasswordReset;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private Boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    private Boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    private Boolean enabled = true;
    private String temporaryPassword;
    private Date validatyTime;
```

Comment: You could use a task scheduler to schedule a "temporary password remover" which would be executed after 1 hour

Comment: As an aside prefer positive Boolean variable names: `boolean accountExpired = false;`. And prefer primitive `boolean` variables over `Boolean` references. Finally prefer the modern `Instant` class over `Date`. `Date` has design problems and is long outdated.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ScheduledTasks to reset all the temporary passwords that have expired and set a flag indicating that temp password is not valid anymore.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: @Scheduled does not allow using the function until a certain time elapses, it’s not that, maybe I’m wrong

Comment: You can have a scheduler to be invoked in every second if you want. In your case, every few minutes should be good enough.

Comment: can somehow get the login time and compare it with the time to create a temporary password?

Comment: then it turns out that need to get the login time like that

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                                // Represents a moment in UTC.
.now()                                 // Capture the current moment, as seen through the wall-clock time of UTC.
.ifAfter(                              // Compare one `Instant` object to another.
    user.whenTemporaryPasswordExpires  // This stored moment (an `Instant`) represents an hour later than the current moment captured when the temporary password was issued. 
)                                      // Returns a boolean.
```

## Expiration, not validity

Track the moment when the password expires. So change the name of your `validityTime` variable to something like `whenTemporaryPasswordExpires`.

When the user attempts another login, you capture the current moment, then compare to the stored `whenTemporaryPasswordExpires`.

## *java.time*

Never use `java.util.Date`. That is one of the terrible date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. Those legacy classes were supplanted entirely years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

### Set the expiration

The first of two phases, set the expiration when generating the temporary password.

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Determine the business policy for how long the temp password is good. Use the `Duration` to track a span of time in terms of days (24-hour chunks of time, not calendar days), hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;  // Policy says temporary password is good for one hour.
```

Do some date-time math, adding the span-of-time (`Duration` object) to the `Instant` to get a new `Instant` representing a future moment. Notice how *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so a new `Instant` object is produced with values based on the original.

```
Instant expires = instant.plus( d ) ; // Date-time math, adding the one hour to the current moment gets us a moment 1 hour in the future.
```

Store that expiration moment as a member variable on your class.

```
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails {

    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    …
    private Instant whenTemporaryPasswordExpires;
    …
}
```

Assign the future moment to the variable.

```
user.whenTemporaryPasswordExpires = expires ;
```

## Compare current moment to expiration

Phase Two, when user attempts a login, we see if the current moment is later than the expiration. The `Instant` class has comparison methods such as `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

```
boolean expired = Instant.now().isAfter( user.whenTemporaryPasswordExpires ) ;
if( expired ) {
    // TODO: Display error message about temp pw expired. Offer new temp pw.
} else {  // Else, not expired. Accept temporary password.
    // TODO: Check submitted password to see if it matches temporary password issued earlier.
}
```

Notice that all the code above uses [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). There is no need to bother with time zones for the expiration logic. If you want to display the expiration, search Stack Overflow to learn about `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`.

---

In discussion above, I ignored the obvious problem that we never store passwords as such. We use salting & hashing, but that is an altogether different discussion.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).